# Bootstrap web app showing too small in mobile when published to Ubuntu server

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ubuntu, mobile, yeoman

So I created a web app using Yeoman webapp template with bootstrap and sass. When I deploy it locally with 'gulp build' in my Windows PC and run it using 'gulp serve' everything looks good in mobile (using browser emulator and also publishing it with XAMP and viewing it from my iPhone). 
However, when I 'gulp build' and upload the 'dist' folder to my ubuntu server, the page looks good in desktop but in mobile everything looks very small. Bootstrap grid reorganizes panels as expected but font and Facebook comments plugin appear very small.
Again, using Windows 10 as server everything looks nice in mobile and, as mentioned in many other posts, I am using the meta:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, not sure if it helps but the apache version on both Windows and Ubuntu machines is 2.4

Comment: You have multiple `head` tags for some reason.

Comment: Thanks vanburen for your comment. Something I noticed is that the page published in apache Ubuntu somehow contains "framesets" in the code which I understand is a tag not supported in HTML5. Because of this we see multiple head/body tags... Now why does this frameset got inserted in there?
Checked on apache/Windows10 and those frameset does not appear in the page source code.

Comment: Please do not change your title or question if you solve it; that does not mark the question as solved in the UI or show the solution to people who search for your question. Instead, put the answer in the big Answer text field below (which you have done) and after a day or so click the green check mark at the upper-left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: It ended up that problem was not related neither to code nor to Ubuntu/apache.
I am using a domain purchased in GoDaddy and they have a feature for "masking forwarding" which means that the domain is automatically redirected to my IP address but this option inserts "framesets" into the code to keep the URL masked with the domain name.
To solve the problem, you need to disable any kind of forwarding in GoDaddy (remove any redirect configuration you have) and instead add an A record as described [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238).